sudoreplay - When does /var/log/sudo-io run, or can we force start it?
I had a bunch of episodes of too many sudoreplay logs, that is, directories under /var/log/sudo-io, at the point some filesystem commands, like find or du, became irresponsive.
Following sudoers manual, I disabled some unnecessary logs with NOLOG_INPUT: NOLOG_OUTPUT: and added this to sudoers.d:
Defaults maxseq=1000

A couple hours later, the logs are exactly the same, meaning nothing was purged.
I don't know if sudoreplay purges itself at specific intervals, when hitting maxseq, or needs some service reload, or whatever else.
Is there any way to start sudoreplay purge? Or to predict when it will run?

use logrotatote(.d) as any other service using it since it was released

@djdomi How to set up logrotate to act on directory count, instead of file size/age? Can it prevent logging of specific sudo commands?

logrotatote can execute scripts, so you are free to code what you want to use or solve

@djdomi The point is that sudoreplay already purges, so it seems overkill to me to rewrite from scratch a functionality which already exists. I just need to know what's wrong in my setup. Plus, logrotate can't filter inputs.
